# Pandasql conditional join with one result returned from right table

Tags: sql, pandas

I'm doing an analysis in Pandas which requires a few conditional joins for which it is very practical to switch over to SQL with pandasql. Unfortunately I'm having a problem with one of the joins where there are dates involved and the join requires only one result to be returned.

Having table1 where the ID, REGION require an exact match on table2 and DATE requires an approximate match where the DATE in table1 needs to be <= then the DATE in table2 and the closest one (smallest day difference).

| ID | REGION | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | ABC | 12.05.2021 |
| 111 | ZDF | 14.02.2021 |
| 222 | DEF | 31.12.2021 |

And table2 with the additional column INDIC which needs to be returned in the join

| ID | REGION | DATE | INDIC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | ABC | 30.06.2021 | Y |
| 111 | ABC | 12.08.2021 | X |
| 111 | ABC | 15.10.2021 | Z |
| 222 | DEF | 08.10.2021 | A |
| 222 | DEF | 05.01.2022 | B |
| 222 | DEF | 13.04.2022 | C |

The result I would expect of the join should look like:

[image]

The code that I have for the moment is:

```
SELECT df_left.*, df_right.[INDIC]
FROM tbl1_df AS df_left
LEFT JOIN tbl2_df AS df_right
ON df_left.[ID] =  df_right.[ID]
AND df_left.[REGION] = df_right.[REGION]
WHERE  (df_left.[DATE] <= df_right.[DATE])
```

This will at the moment present an unwanted but expected result:
[image]

Can anyone suggest how the SQL part should look like?

Comment: kindly share the data as text, not pics. You can solve this in pandas; even if you solve it in sql (due to size or other reasons), pandasql is not the way to go as it is quite slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the best solution so far with below code:

```
SELECT tbl1_df.*, tbl2_df.[INDIC]
    FROM tbl1_df 
    LEFT JOIN tbl2_df 
    ON tbl1_df.[ID] =  tbl2_df.[ID]
    AND tbl2_df.[DATE] = (
        SELECT MIN(DATE) FROM tbl2_df WHERE (tbl2_df.[ID] = tbl1_df.[ID]) AND (tbl1_df.[DATE] <= tbl2_df.[DATE]) AND (tbl1_df.[REGION] = tbl2_df.[REGION])
        )
```

Which gives a following result and I can easily deal with the NONE later on.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`pandas.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with `forward` search policy.

A `forward` search selects the first row in the right DataFrame whose `on` key is *greater than or equal* to the left’s key.

To use `merge_asof`, you need ensure the merged `on` column is sorted.

```py
df1['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['DATE'], dayfirst=True)
df2['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['DATE'], dayfirst=True)
df1 = df1.sort_values(by=['DATE'])
df2 = df2.sort_values(by=['DATE'])
```

With the sort requirements and the forward search, it can meet your needs:

> `DATE` requires an approximate match where the DATE in table1 needs to be `<=` then the DATE in table2 and the closest one (smallest day difference)

```py
out = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='DATE', by=['ID', 'REGION'], direction='forward')
out['DATE'] = out['DATE'].dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
```

```
print(out)

    ID REGION        DATE INDIC
0  111    ZDF  14.02.2021   NaN
1  111    ABC  12.05.2021     Y
2  222    DEF  31.12.2021     B
```